# Source code and Firebug give different html for top links

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I need to correct this as the path in html source code is incorrect - somehow these broken links are changed to correct ones in the browser and when I look at the top links in firebug, the paths are correct. Anyway, I suppose Google sees those as broken links. The codes look like this:

**Firebug**

```
<div id="topLinks" class="placeholder" rel="top.links"><ul class="links">
  <li class="first"><a href="http://www.domain.com/customer/account/" title="Omat tiedot ">Omat tiedot </a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/wishlist/" title="Toivelista">Toivelista</a></li>
  <li class=" last"><a href="http://www.domain.com/customer/account/login/" title="Kirjaudu sisään">Kirjaudu sisään</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**HTML Source code of the same position**

```
<div id="topLinks" class="placeholder" rel="top.links">
  <ul class="links">
  <li class="first"><a title="My Account" href="customer/account/">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a title="My Wishlist" href="wishlist/">My Wishlist</a></li>
  <li><a class="top-link-cart" title="My Cart" href="checkout/cart/">My Cart</a></li>
  <li><a class="top-link-checkout" title="Checkout" href="/checkout/">Checkout</a></li>
  <li class=" last"><a title="Log In" href="customer/account/login/">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I got to say I'm desperate to fix this, I really hope someone can help me out!

Comment: would be great if you can provide the link where you see this.

Comment: Sure - thought I should avoid that, but it is www.veloshop.fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site uses the AOE Static extension. The Javascript from http://example.com/js/aoestatic/common.js will find the top links block and then replace it via an AJAX call to http://example.com/phone/call/index/?getBlocks%5BtopLinks%5D=top.links producing the translated version to improve cachability of the page.

Comment: Cool - thanks! Disabling AOE Static removed the forced part completely, however, the top links seem to be relative not absolute lists and now the 404 links are all over the place. What might cause this?

Comment: I guess it's actually another problem that is not related to this case anymore.

Comment: After removing aoestatic.xml file, everything was fixed - so happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Firebug shows you the html as it is at that point in time based on the DOM of the page, which includes any manipulation done via Javascript. A similar issue on [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634959/html-shown-in-view-source-is-different-to-the-html-shown-in-firebug).

Viewing the HTML source is the output your site produces. Additionally viewing the HTML source acts like re-loading the page - which in some circumstances will mean you end up viewing a different page. Prime example of this is if you want to view the source on the checkout/success page where you end up viewing the empty cart page since the success page is only ever displayed once.

Comment: That makes sense! I separated and un-minified all js files to figure out which js file could be doing this. So far it's still a mystery as none of the js files are using those translations, but at least some are related to some translate functions.